# PWM dc motor using L293D weak sound

Tags: python, rpi.gpio, pwm

This is the problem: using [this tutorial](https://business.tutsplus.com/tutorials/controlling-dc-motors-using-python-with-a-raspberry-pi--cms-20051) and *Adafruit_Python_GPIO* libs when start pwm and step up with DutyCycle and frequency I hear a weak sound from motor but unfortunely it doesn't move.

Wiring

[image]

Code

```
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
    from time import sleep

    ENABLE_PIN = 25
    IN1 = 24
    IN2 = 23
    ENGINE_FREQ = 500

    class pump:
        def __init__(self):
            self.enable_pin = ENABLE_PIN
            self.in1_pin = IN1
            self.in2_pin = IN2

            GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

            GPIO.setup(self.enable_pin, GPIO.OUT)
            GPIO.setup(self.in1_pin, GPIO.OUT)
            GPIO.setup(self.in2_pin, GPIO.OUT)

            self.pwm = GPIO.PWM(self.enable_pin, ENGINE_FREQ)

        def start(self):
            self.pwm.start(0)

            GPIO.output(self.in1_pin, True)
            GPIO.output(self.in2_pin, False)
            self.pwm.ChangeDutyCycle(100)

        def stop(self):
            self.pwm.stop()
            #GPIO.cleanup()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        p = pump()
        p.start()
        sleep(5)
        p.stop()
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The code looks fine.

That suggests

- loose wiring
- weak batteries
- stalled motor

Comment: putting batteries pack directly to motor, it work's fine.

Comment: @pepperav It's a good idea to also edit such diagnostic information into your question so all relevant information is in one place.  The schematic looks fine.  Perhaps your wiring doesn't match the schematic.  The L293D will drop a volt or so.

Comment: I have set dtoverlay=pwm-2chan in /boot/config.txt

Comment: @pepperav For any particular reason?  I repeat edit new information into your question.

Comment: because I thought that PWM was disabled. I'm using raspbian jessie lite.

Comment: Can I use a GPIO pin number different from GPIO18 to erogate PWM?

Comment: RPi.GPIO uses software timed PWM.  You can use it on all GPIO.